# Liquibase and Docker

Tags: docker, liquibase

I am trying to run Liquibase from a Docker Container.  I found the run statement, but when I run, it exits almost immediately so the container is no longer running.
This is the command i am using. Thanks!

docker run liquibase/liquibase --driver=org.postgresql.Driver --classpath=/usr/share/java/postgresql.jar --url="jdbc:postgresql://host.docker.internal/mydb" --changeLogFile=changelog.xml --username=user --password=superobviouspwd generateChangeLog

Comment: did you have a look at the liquibase container's log yet to potentially figure out the root cause? `docker ps -a` followed by `docker logs <container-name>`

Answer (score 1):

Just for others that may be looking for the answer to this question, it was answered [here in the liquibase forums](https://forum.liquibase.org/#Topic/49382000002138021).

To try and summarize the changelog was referencing a windows path "C:.." and the Docker container is using *nix pathing "/some/file/oer/there".

Answer (score 0):

From your Docker folder run this

`docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash YourDockerImageID -s`

you will start the container and enter it, be able to investigate what's happening inside etc. See this post for more info
https://vsupalov.com/debug-docker-container/#getting-interactive